# jQuery - Set input range max to variable

Tags: jquery

I want to set my `max` on the input to be the difference between `.total` and `.sold`. Why is the `max` attribute not being set on the `.qty` input?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var total = $(".total").html();
  var sold = $(".sold").html();
  var available = $(".available").html(total - sold);
  $(".qty").attr({
    max: available
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
sold<span class="sold">3</span> total
<span class="total">10</span> available
<span class="available"></span>
<input type="range" min="1" value="1" class="qty" name='quantity' oninput="num.value = this.value">
<output id="num">0</output>
```

Comment: Remove available var you do not need that - just add this in `attr` -> `max: +total - +sold`

Comment: like this -> `$(document).ready(function() {
  var total = $(".total").html();
  var sold = $(".sold").html();
  $(".qty").attr({
    max: +total - +sold
  });
});` works the same way but less code is better always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `var available = $(".available").html(total - sold);` returns a jQuery collection not a number. Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var total = $(".total").html();
  var sold = $(".sold").html();
  var available = total - sold; // now available is a number
  $(".available").html(available);
  $(".qty").attr({
    max: available
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
sold<span class="sold">3</span> total
<span class="total">10</span> available
<span class="available"></span>
<input type="range" min="1" value="1" class="qty" name='quantity' oninput="num.value = this.value">
<output id="num">0</output>
```